# How to open project folder from Visual Studio in Windows Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'd like to have easy access to my project's folder from within Visual Studio. What do I do to open its folder in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open the Solution Explorer >> right-click your project >> select Open Folder in Windows Explorer.

This has been tested on Visual Studio 2010. It will probably work in any other Visual Studio with a Solution Explorer.

See screenshots:

[image]

Comment: Confirmed working in VS 2015. Amazing this option isn't enabled for single files, only the solution itself.

Comment: @Kyle are you talking about the bottom part of the image?

Comment: Well blow me down.... I was talking more of right clicking in the solution explorer on a single file, missed the bottom part of the image :)

Comment: Yea that's still one extra action. Maybe somebody made an extension that adds such an option to Solution Explorer's context menu. If not, you could create one yourself and publish it for others' convenience.

Comment: Possibly, I'm happy with your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

You can open some of **Soluion Explorer's** items (**folders**, **projects**, **solutions**) in File Explorer by it's right click menus subitem "**Open Folder in File Explorer**".

[image: Open Folder in File Explorer]

Also you can open opened documents containing folder by right click opened documents tab and "**Open Containing Folder**".

[image: Open Containing Folder]

Comment: What in the world is "File Explorer"?

Comment: @CodyGray It is the operating system window in Windows which shows you the files on the disk.  It is analogous to the Mac's Finder.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way...

I map a key chord to the command

[image]

Unfortunately, this only works when a project node is selected, probably because solution folders aren't *actually* folders and therefore it cannot be guaranteed that they actually match a folder in the file system.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation about the other folders

Comment: @MikeYoung Ironically, my office just experienced odd behaviors in production due to this fact this very morning (folders named differently than their representation in the solution).  I thought VS was going to change how these structures are synched with the file system, but apparently they haven't yet.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to the answer opening the solution folder, there is an easy way in adding an `open with` for single files in the "Solution explorer". Just right click on a file, select `Open With...`, then `Add` a new entry:

[image]

As arguments you can type `/select,%1` which opens the explorer with the current file selected.

Comment: Sometimes it pays off to read all the comments. This is what I wanted! Thanks