# Recover deleted project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project, recovery, recover

I was creating a website using visual studio and accidentally deleted that project folder. :(

It was three months project. Is there anyway to get it back? visual studio 2013

Comment: was it the folder containing your project? have you deleted it from disk?

Answer (score 3):

1. Are you using any [Source control management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system (e.g. [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/), [git](http://git-scm.com/about) etc...)?
   If so, this is the time for a [revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html). If not, [you should](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)...
2. Was the project deleted from your disk? If not (it shouldn't..),
   just re add it to your solution. Chances are it is still in your solution folder
   ([You can easily open it via Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704235/how-to-open-project-folder-from-visual-studio-in-windows-explorer)).
3. If it was deleted from your HDD, this is where things starts to get tricky. Try restoring deleted data from your disk.
   You will need a software to help you with this task (e.g. [this one](http://www.icare-recovery.com/windows-7-recovery/recover-shift-deleted-folder-windows-7.html) was randomly selected using a simple google search).
4. In case nothing of the above works you can take your HDD to a professional lab to restore the deleted data.
   If it is just a small project, I wouldn't bother. If it is not, Shame on you for not using SCM ;0)
5. Good luck...
6. If nothing of the above works, I am sorry for your loss...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
1. It was individual project. So I didn't use any SCM. I'll definitely do it next time.
2.It was deleted from hard disk.
3.I tried different recovery soft wares. But it wasn't successful. :(
4.I didn't go to professional lab, I don't know any professional lab .
I started that project again.... such a waste :(

Comment: @Kasun Good luck. Sometimes the best teacher is bad experience... Regarding the recovery softwares, It is best to immediately disconnect the HDD and install the SW on another computer and then attach the HDD to that computer. This is for minimizing the chances that the physical location of the data is being overwritten by new data (possibly by the installation of the recovery SW itself!), and being lost for ever...

Comment: Thanks Avi Turner. After that deletion I used hard for a week. this might be the problem for recovery. Anyway, I installed svn to new project. This was a great lesson for me. Thank you very much for your advice and your valuable time.